# Validating XML against local DTD. Problems with EntityResolver2

Tags: java, xml, sax

I have to validate some XML files against a local DTD file. The XML could be without DOCTYPE. Here is the body of my main method:

```
XMLReader reader;
    DTDManipulator dtdhandler;
    XMLValidationEvendHandler errorhandler = new XMLValidationEvendHandler();
    try {
        dtdhandler = new DTDManipulator();
        dtdhandler.setDTDentity("file:///Users/hp/Desktop/BOX/A/Ordinanze.dtd");
        reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        reader.setErrorHandler(errorhandler);
        reader.setEntityResolver(dtdhandler);   
        //reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/use-entity-resolver2", true);
        reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation",true);

        reader.parse(new InputSource("OT201011120071_045NODTD.xml"));
        if(errorhandler.isNoerrors()) {
            System.out.println("SUCCESS!");
        }
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int i=0; i<errorhandler.getExceptionOccurred().length; i++) System.out.println(errorhandler.getExceptionOccurred()[i].getMessage());
    System.exit(0);
```

DTD implements EntityResolver2:

```
public class DTDManipulator implements EntityResolver2 {

private String dtd;

public void setDTDentity(String entity) {
    System.out.println("DTDManipulator.setDTDentity:");
    System.out.println(" - entity = "+entity);
    dtd = entity;
}

@Override
public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
        throws SAXException, IOException {
    System.out.println("DTDManipulator.resolveEntity:");
    System.out.println(" - publicId = "+publicId);
    System.out.println(" - systemId = "+systemId);
    System.out.println(" - get back = "+"");
    return new InputSource(dtd);
}

@Override
public InputSource getExternalSubset(String name, String baseURI)
        throws SAXException, IOException {
    System.out.println("DTDManipulator.getExternalSubset:");
    System.out.println(" - name = "+name);
    System.out.println(" - baseURI = "+baseURI);
    System.out.println(" - get back = "+dtd);
    return new InputSource(dtd);
}

@Override
public InputSource resolveEntity(String name, String publicId,
        String baseURI, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException {
    System.out.println("DTDManipulator.resolveEntity:");
    System.out.println(" - name = "+name);
    System.out.println(" - publicId = "+publicId);
    System.out.println(" - baseURI = "+baseURI);
    System.out.println(" - systemId = "+systemId);
    System.out.println(" - get back = "+dtd);
    return new InputSource(dtd);
}
```

}

}

When I try to validate an XML whitout DTD references inside i got an unexpected behavior: no DOCTYPE is added before the document root, the method `getExternalSubset` of DTDManipulator is never called.
I can't guess why, what am I missing? Thanks in advance, excuse my english.

Francesco

Comment: Have you checked that the feature `http://xml.org/sax/features/use-entity-resolver2` is true on the XMLReader instance?

Comment: Sorry forty-two I miss a comment. How did you get your XMLReader instance? Did you use a `javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory`?

Comment: Hmm, now I'm confused! Do you set the feature, or does it throw an exception?.

Comment: When I set it it throws an exception.

Comment: Ok, then your XMLreader is not a SAX2 compliant. What are you using?

Comment: I use `org.xml.sax.XMLReader`. How to get a SAX2 compliant one?

Comment: XMLReader is an interface. For example, using SAXParserFactory on standard JDK 1.6, you can get one from  SAXParser#getXMLReader().

Comment: May you give me some source samples? I think I'm still missing something. Thank you.